# Setting up Automatic NDK Builds in Eclipse do not work yet

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, android-ndk-r5

i new to the ndk programming.And i wanna my eclipse in linux os can automatically build the the content of folder,jni into the folder,libs via ndk-build.And i follow the tutorial,http://mobilepearls.com/labs/ndk-builder-in-eclipse/to do so.For testing it whether works,i import the example of the ndk release,hello-jni.And because the example does not contain the folder libs,which will has the .so built from the jni's c source,i make a new folder under my new project.And then,i try to append a comment in the source,/HelloJni/jni/hello-jni.c,like:

```
/*hello
*/
```

but there seems to be nothing happened in my folder,libs.
And here is my setting of my ndk-builder:
location:
/home/kaiwii/android_related/android-ndk-r7b/ndk-build
working directory:
${workspace_loc:/HelloJni}
refersh's specified folder is:
libs
build's specified folder is:
jni
And finally,i need to mention that when i open the c source,hello-jni.c,it will prompt syntax error and `Unresolved inclusion: <string.h>`
Any one have the same problem or any idea?thx